# localStorage.getItem() always returns null even when value exists

Tags: vue.js, local-storage

Im not sure If I am doing something wrong or if I have a typo somewhere, but I am trying to compare dates in a vue project but the value I pull from my local storage always returns null even when I can see the value clearly exists when I check my local storage. so here is the set up.

after making a request I set the expires date in local storage like so

```
retrieveToken({ commit }, credentials) {

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios.post('/login', {
              username: credentials.username,
              password: credentials.password,
          })
          .then(response => {
              const token = response.data.access_token
              const date = new Date(moment().add(30, 'seconds').toDate());
              localStorage.setItem('expires_on', date)
              localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
              resolve(response)
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log(error.response.data)
              reject(error)
          })
      })
    },
```

I can then see that the `expires on` has been placed in my local storage
[image]

I then want to use a getter to retrieve that value like so

```
tokenExpires() {
      return localStorage.getItem('expires_on')
    },
```

So i can use like this

```
computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['tokenExpires']),
    },
methods: {
     destroySessionIfTokenIsExpired() {
            const current = new Date(moment())
            const expires = this.tokenExpires
            const currentDate = moment(current).format('YYYYMMDDHHMMSS')
            const expiresDate = moment(expires).format('YYYYMMDDHHMMSS')
                console.log(this.tokenExpires)
                console.log(expiresDate)
            if(currentDate >= expiresDate) {
                this.$store.dispatch('destroyToken')
                .then(() => {
                    this.$router.push('/login')
                    alert('Your Session Has Expired, Please Log Back In')
                })
            } else return;
        }
       }
```

but when I run this method and console.log(this.tokenExpires) it returns null and I am not sure why. If anybody can see what I am doing wrong please let me know!!

*Update, my issue is that I am trying to watch the routes and run a comparison of timestamps to see if the session is still valid but as pointed out, the `getter` does not have enough time to compute the value before the method runs, so any suggestions on how I could get around that would be awesome. here is the route watch method

```
watch: {
        '$route': function(to, from) {
            this.destroySessionIfTokenIsExpired()
        }
    },
```

Comment: When do you call `retrieveToken`? It's likely that the `expires_on` is not available yet when `tokenExpires` property is being computed, because `retrieveToken` have not gotten result back from server yet. Besides, `localStorage` is not reactive, so it won't trigger Vue's recalculation.

Comment: @YongQuan, I see what your saying. Is there another way I could pull the value from localStorage without using a getter? if I refresh the page, it gives it enough time to get `tokenExpires` but I am also watching the routes as well which is where I am running into a problem. I will post my route watch method

Comment: why not just simple `const expires = localStorage.getItem('expires_on')` in your `destroySessionIfTokenIsExpired` function?

Comment: @YongQuan Ill give it a shot

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851711/vuex-store-properties-not-reactive-when-using-computed-property) can give you another perspective.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @YongQuan I have this solution.

```
methods: {
        ...mapActions(['destroyToken']),
        destroySessionIfTokenIsExpired() {
            const expiresOn = localStorage.getItem('expires_on')
            const expiresDate = moment(expiresOn).format('YYYYMMDDHHMMSS')
            if(expiresOn == null) return;
            const current = new Date(moment())
            const currentDate = moment(current).format('YYYYMMDDHHMMSS')
            if(currentDate >= expiresDate) {
                this.$store.dispatch('destroyToken')
                this.$router.push('/login')
            } else return;
        }
    },
    watch: {
        '$route': function(to, from) {
            this.destroySessionIfTokenIsExpired()
        }
    },
```

Instead of using a `getter` I just set the `localStorage.getItem('expires_on') to a variable inside the method. Thanks @YongQuan