# Vue displayed text not updated after reactive changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following Vue template:

```
  <b-button :disabled="!canVote" v-on:click="upvote" class="mr-1" variant="outline-secondary" size="sm">
    {{ comment.up }}
    {{ upvotes }}
    {{ downvotes }}
  </b-button>
```

The mustache enclosed properties are not updated even they were modified and I can see in the console that Vue holds the updated value.

What I have tried:

```
props: {
  comment: Object,
},

computed: {
  upvotes() {
    return this.$store.getters.GET_COMMENT(this.comment._id).up;
  },
  downvotes() {
    return this.comment.down;
  },

methods: {
  async upvote() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('COMMENT_VOTE', {
      vote: 1,
      itemId: this.itemId,
      commentId: this.comment._id,
    });
    console.log(this.comment);
    console.log(this.$store.getters.GET_COMMENT(this.comment._id));
  },
```

[image]
[image]

store:

```
mutations: {
SET_VOTE: (state, payload) => {
  const { commentId, vote, userId, nickname } = payload;
  const comment = state.comments[commentId];
  if (!comment.votes) {
    comment.votes = [];
  }
  comment.votes.push({ vote, user: { nickname, id: userId } });

  if (vote === 1) {
    comment.up += 1;
  } else {
    comment.down += 1;
  }
},
actions: {
COMMENT_VOTE: async (context, payload) => {
  const body = { itemId: payload.itemId, vote: payload.vote };
  await post('API', `/comments/${payload.commentId}/votes`, body, context);
  const mutation = {
    commentId: payload.commentId,
    vote: payload.vote,
    userId: context.rootState.userId,
    nickname: context.rootState.userNickname,
  };
  context.commit('SET_VOTE', mutation);
},
```

PS this has not helped either:

```
Vue.set(comment, 'up', comment.up + 1);
```

Comment: how does comment vote looks like in the store

Comment: I had the same problem with you the other day, you can try `this.$set()` or `this.$nextTick()`, These methods apply to me

Comment: @jeremyjone can you elaborate your comment more deeply? I am not sure if I understand correctly. I will update my question with the mutation.

Comment: @LeosLiterak i see but how does the code looks like in your vuex store? it matters how you change the variable in your store

Comment: thats `SET_VOTE` i guess its an commit. and how does `COMMENT_VOTE`  look like?

Comment: I guess `computed` funciton not work, I'm still looking at the specifics. But I changed it to a method and tried to call it in `this.$nextTick` after each update to force the update, which solved my problem.

Comment: This situation only happens when `your prop` is `Object`, which is perfect when I change the type.

Comment: Sorry, my Vue knowledge is not sufficient to follow you. Can you provide an answer with code sample to try? This is not relying on property and it does not work either: return this.$store.getters.GET_COMMENT(this.comment._id).up;

Comment: Any reason you're not using `mapState` and `mapGetters`?

Comment: I like more verbose way. Is mapState relevant to this trouble? I thought it is just a syntax sugar.

Comment: How's your state looks like? Might be because of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41856330/12397250

Comment: The `if (!comment.votes) { comment.votes = [] }` code looks problematic. [Vue cannot detect property addions.](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects) You might also have other similar code not shown here like that.

Comment: You already pass the comment down as a prop. Retrieving the upvotes from the store is completely redundant when you can just use `this.comment.up` (you even do it on the downvotes). Please add the code that shows where you pass the prop down to your component. Or better yet, try and recreate the issue in a codesandbox.

Comment: I have created the codesandbox and it is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-taussig-v8u4b?file=/src/components/Comments.vue. But voting actually works! I have no idea why. This is the repository: https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/tree/comment_refactoring. That would be a nightmare to identify the root cause.